# Services add several nodes at once

Tags: services

I am using Drupal 7 with Services module (version 3.x). I want to add several nodes at once. When i try one it is okay.

```
{"type":"article","title":"Test article 1","body":{"und":[{"value":"test body!"}]},"language" :"und"}
```

But when I try something like this i can't

```
{"type":"article","title":"Test article 1","body":{"und":[{"value":"test body!"}]},"language" :"und"},{"type":"article","title":"Test article 2","body":{"und":[{"value":"test body!"}
```

Is there a way to make this happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services default functionality for node creation is one by one. If you want to create multiple node at once then you should write your custom service using `hook_services_resources()`. You can find some example about how to write custom service [Click Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/783460)

Comment: Thank you about fast response. I also want to create node with different user. I logged in as administrator and add extra filed "uid":"60" but my node is created from my administrator name, not from user with ID 60.

Comment: Using your custom service you can create every single node from your desired user id.

Comment: Thank you again. I will create custom service module for several nodes. But for user i was wrong with the field. I looked closely in service code and find that needed field is "name" not "uid"